# getting selected value of Combobox python

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Hi I have the following code

```
def create(self):
    geo = StringVar()
    city = ttk.Combobox(gui, textvariable=geo,state="readonly")
    city.config(values=self.geo)
    city.pack()
    city.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.cityselection)


def cityselection(self,event):
    selected=event
    print(selected)
```

I want to send the selected value of from the Combobox to cityselection function but when I print it I only get

> VirtualEvent event x=0 y=0

and it does not matter which value I choose I will always get the above output instate of for e.g: London or Toronto,

Comment: use `self.geo` in both methods to have access to selected element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me :

```
def create(self):
        print(self.geo)
        strgeo="\n".join(str(x) for x in self.geo)

        print(strgeo)
        city = ttk.Combobox(gui, textvariable=self.stringGeo, state="readonly",width=30)
        city.config(values=strgeo)
        city.pack()
        city.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",self.selectedCity)

    def selectedCity(self,event):
        selected=self.stringGeo.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands you cannot retrieve the value of `geo`, since it is not defined as an attribute of your class, but in the local scope of `create`.  What you *can* do is declaring `geo` as a static attribute and then call it from within your method when you need it.

```
class(object):

    geo = StringVar()
    geos = ('NY','LA','RY','...')

    def __init__(self,#....
        #...

    def create(self):
        city = ttk.Combobox(gui, textvariable=self.geo,state="readonly")
        city.config(values=self.geos) 
        city.pack()
        city.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.cityselection)


    def cityselection(self,event):
        selected=self.geo.get()
        print(selected)
```

Actually, [`event`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events) is not what you think it is.

Comment: the list I am trying to work with is <class 'numpy.ndarray'> so I think when the combo box is displaying it display the whole array as one

Comment: @Amin I am not sure to understand why you involve a list in the discussion. BTW, if `foo` is the name of your numpy.ndarray, what you can do to turn it into a so-called python builtin `list`, is `foo.tolist()`.